# Regex contains words if no negative words are before it

Tags: python, regex

I want to grab phrases that say *good* or *great*, but are not negated by the words *not* or *isn't* **before** it.

```
sents= ["good words",                   # Words after phrase
        "not good words",
        "isn't good words",

        "great words",
        "not great words",
        "isn't great words",



        "words good",                   # Words before phrase
        "words not good",
        "words isn't good"

        "words great",
        "words not great",
        "words isn't great"


        
        "words good words",             # Words before and after phrase
        "words not good words",
        "words isn't good words",

        "words great words",
        "words not great words",
        "words isn't great words",
]
```

I want to return

```
good words
words good
words good words

great words
words great
words great words
```

What is the regular expression that will let me do this? In theory, I want to be able to have a list of words that are only found if the string does not contain any from a list of negatives precede it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 negative lookbehind assertions in python:

```
(?<!isn't )(?<!not )\b(?:good|great)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lw104I/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!isn't )`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if we have `isn't` followed by a single space behind us
- `(?<!not )`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if we have `not` followed by a single space behind us
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:good|great)`: Match `good` or `great`
- `\b`: Word boundary

**Code:**

```
>>> sents= ["good words",                   # Words after phrase
...         "not good words",
...         "isn't good words",
...         "great words",
...         "not great words",
...         "isn't great words",
...         "words good",                   # Words before phrase
...         "words not good",
...         "words isn't good",
...         "words great",
...         "words not great",
...         "words isn't great",
...         "words good words",             # Words before and after phrase
...         "words not good words",
...         "words isn't good words",
...         "words great words",
...         "words not great words",
...         "words isn't great words",
... ]
>>> reg = re.compile(r"(?<!isn't )(?<!not )\b(?:good|great)\b")
>>> for s in sents:
...     if reg.search(s):
...             print(s)
...
good words
great words
words good
words great
words good words
words great words
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **look behind**, in this case **negative** since there is a version for *positive* as well. And you can use it as simple as:

```
(?<!not\s)great
```

In this example the word **`not`** cannot exists before **`great`**.

Here is a how it may look like:

```
(?<!not\s)(?<!isn't\s)(great|good)
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KNExb2/2/)